# Get keys and values drop a map in IE with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to iterate threw a map to get Keys and values, but nothing is working on internet explorer. I tried everything, in firefox (.keys(), forEach(), Symbole.iterator, for loop, .entries()...) but in IE I had always errors. Can anyone help me please ? Thank you

Comment: IE doesn't support some of the newer ES6 and above methods. There are polyfills for many of them you can use  if you need to support IE. New features , older browser

Comment: which IE version? 
IE 11 has a limited support of JS Maps.

Comment: A side note: Microsoft will drop IE11 support (and the whole IE product line) in 3 months from now. With this information, are you sure supporting IE is worth the effort?

Comment: Charlietfl : I saw babbel as polyfills I will try to use it ! Thank you

Comment: Alex : unfortunatly my company work only with IE... the version is IE 11

Comment: @AlexShesterov **AFAIK**, MS will **not** drop IE11 support (as many news titles say), it just drops e.g. Office 365 being supported for IE11. From [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/internet-explorer-microsoft-edge): "Internet Explorer is a component of the Windows operating system and follows the Lifecycle Policy for the product on which it is installed." = Windows 10 most likely. I would be glad to be misunderstood, however..

Comment: @Erika: please provide at leas some sample simple code